# Apache authentication on IBMi AS/400

Tags: apache, basic-authentication, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to place an entire directory behind Apache Authentication on an IBMi AS/400 V7R2.  I need to specify credentials which have no relationship with the AS/400 other than the fact they are defined in a file on the IFS. I'm new to the IBMi world and am unsure where Apache was installed.  I know I need to include a handful of Apache modules, but don't know where those are.  I also do not know where I can find the `htpasswd.exe` equivalent so I was going to be hopeful and use http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator-windows/.  The file which contains the credentials must have the password encrypted as well.  I've tried various strings in a `which` command in PASE with no luck.

I've also seen two different ways to include the password file (`PasswdFile` and `AuthUserFile`) but can't find the difference.  My assumption is that `PasswdFile` is used for actual IBMi system users and `AuthUserFile` is meant to be used with a `.htpasswd.exe` generated file for arbitrary users.

Code Examples I've tried:

```
<Directory "/path/to/secure/directory">
    PasswdFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "To access the requested page, please enter your login credentials."
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Options
    Options Indexes
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

OR

```
<Directory "/path/to/secure/directory">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Secure Login"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

The modules I was going to include to cover all of my bases until it was working include:

- mod_access.so
- mod_auth.so
- mod_auth_anon.so
- mod_auth_dbm.so
- mod_auth_digest.so

Has anyone done this before, or knows how to do this on IBMi and can lend some guidance?  Most articles specific to Apache for IBMi usually explain how to authenticate against existing IBMi users and then everything for `.htpasswd` base authentication is not specific to IBMi, so I don't know if Apache for IBMi is different in this case or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I would say you're stuck using either the system user ids and password or validation lists.  check out this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/httpservers/doc/v4r4/wmg/RZAG2M07.HTM#HDRPASSWDF

Comment: This definitely looks like it will do the job.  Once I am able to get it working I'll post an update to confirm.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this.  I had to go on a business trip for a week and now I'm trying to figure out how to create a *VLDL type file with credentials stored in it.  I'm not too savvy on an IBMi.

Comment: @bvstone Validation list was the right place to look, if you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this works.

I would say you're stuck using either the system user ids and password or validation lists. check out this link: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/httpservers/doc/v4r4/wmg/RZAG2M07.HTM#HDRPASSWDF